# PHP Check which form was submitted

Tags: php, forms, submit, form-submit

I am working on a website where I have 2 forms on 1 page. I use 1 PHP script to check the forms. But if I submit my second form on the page, my website submits the first form. How can I check which form is submitted?

```
<!--// Form 1-->
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="1">

</form>

<!--// Form 2-->
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="2">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $forms = array(1, 2);
    foreach($forms as $form) {

        if($_POST['page_form'] == $form) {
        // All my form validations which are for every form the same.

        }       
    }            
}
```

Comment: I do not see what your problem is $_POST['page_form'] should hold either 1 or 2 and that is the form that have been submitted

Comment: Use different name for submit

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen So you mean this code should work? But it doesn't

Comment: @MarioJohnathan Changed 'submit' to 'submitted' but still don't work right.

Comment: So you mean, `HTML` decides to submit the 1st form when clicking on the second? Never run into that!?!

Comment: Give the submits a different `value` as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537918/multiple-html-forms-on-one-page?

Comment: if you changed the name to submidted to one of the forms did you update the php code to handle the isset($_POST['submitted']) for the form you changed?

Comment: @dollarvar Yes that's what happening!

Comment: @Robbert : Can you post your changes

Comment: @MarioJohnathan this is now my full form handling file http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bax-d4y. I require_once this in my header and then I have 2 files comments.php and contact.php which also are included in the theme (it is Wordpress) These both files have almost the same form, with the same fields.

Comment: This is my test URL, with the 2 forms in it: http://www.639.vc/glasbestellen/producten/test/

Answer (score 12):

What to do it this way:

```
<!--// Form 1-->
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit form">

</form>

<!--// Form 2-->
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="form2" value="Submit form">

</form>
```

And check which form was submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST["form1"]))
   echo "Form 1 have been submitted";
else if(isset($_POST["form2"]))
   echo "Form 2 have been submitted";
```

Comment: If the form is submitted via the Enter key, the submit button variable would be missing.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and i have no problems what so ever:

index.html

```
<!--// Form 1-->
<form method="post" action="submit.php">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="1">

</form>

<!--// Form 2-->
<form method="post" action="submit.php">

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="2">

</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

trying submit with form 1 and data aaa 
result:

```
Array ( [test] => aaa [submit] => Submit [page_form] => 1 )
```

trying submit with form 2 and data bbb
result:

```
Array ( [test] => bbb [submit] => Submit [page_form] => 2 )
```

So i cant see what it is that is not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your question is.
Though a bit convoluted, the code you show should work fine.

If it's a simpler variant you're looking for, I would rather do it that way:

```
if(isset($_POST['page_form'])) 
{
    switch ($_POST['page_form'])
    {
    case "1": // form 1 specific handling
        break;
    case "2": // form 2 specific handling
        break;
    default:
        die ("something's not right there");
    }

    // common handling
}
```

EDIT:

try this out. I would be surprised if it did not work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['page_form'])) 
{
    switch ($_POST['page_form'])
    {
    case "1": // form 1 specific handling
        echo "form 1 submitted<br>";
        break;
    case "2": // form 2 specific handling
        echo "form 2 submitted<br>";
       break;
    default:
        die ("something's not right there");
    }

    // common handling
    foreach ($_POST as $var => $val) echo "$var => $val<br>";
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="1">
</form>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="page_form" value="2">
</form>
```

Now if you don't want a special handling for different forms, simply do this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['page_form'])) 
{   
    // common handling
    foreach ($_POST as $var => $val) echo "$var => $val<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: But for some reason it doesn't work. And I want to use 1 code for both forms to keep it simple and don't want to copy my whole code in each case.

Comment: It does work on my server. If you don't want to do anything special depending on the form submitted, simply remove the switch.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    print_r($_POST);
} ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TRY</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test1" value='test1'>
            <input type="submit" value='Save 1'>
        </form><hr>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test2" value='test2'>
            <input type="submit" value='Save 2'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```