# How to recognize which form to handle in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP file called ***processLogin.php*** (mainly use for login and register) and inside it, contains 2 HTML `<form>` elements. Each form will have a submit button. And i am using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to handle the form.

So is there any way to recognize which form submit to handle, like login form ? or register form. Because both of these `<form>` elements have the action attribute is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

My code:
`<form id="registerUserForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">`

and `<form id="loginUserForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">`

Comment: You can add some query parameter to action like ?form=login

Comment: You can use the name of the submit button to identify which form is been submitted. Like if(isset($_POST['login'])){ // Logic here}

Comment: thank you R4ncid and  Angwa Moses, i will try your provided solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Check which form was submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555927/php-check-which-form-was-submitted)

Comment: yes, your provided post also gave solutions to my question, thank you @kmoser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can handle form by checking which form was clicked.

Like this.

```
<form id="loginUserForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>

<form id="registerUserForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="register" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And then write the php code to handle the form like below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register')){

// Write code to handle registration here

}

if(isset($_POST['login')){

// Write code to handle login here

}

?>
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, i will try it.

Comment: Try it and if that becomes helpful to you, you can come back and mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the name the same, and instead changing the `value` for each button. Another option would be including a hidden input field in each form with a different value, so you can use that to determine the different forms instead of a "submit" value.

Comment: Yes. that is a good point there too. @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: yes i have tried and it works, we use the name of the input, combined with
if(isset($_POST['nameOfInput')) to handle WHICH type of form that has been submitted