# multiple forms on a single PHP page

Tags: php

Im having issues with a ''profile'' page where users will be able to change their username, email, name, password and so on but it seems to have conflicts when i have more than 1 form on the page as they all work individually?

I could be missing something obvious so if anyone could help id much appreciate it.

Base

```
<?php 
require 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>
<h1><p>Hello <?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></a>!</p></h1> 

<h4><p>You joined the MMOunition community <?php echo escape($user->data()->joined); ?></a></p></h4> 

<alert_banner>
<?php
if(Session::exists('home')) {
    echo '<p>', Session::flash('home'), '</p>';
}
?>
</alert_banner>
<br />
<form action="changeusername.php" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </div>
</form>


<br />
<form action="changepassword.php" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_current">Current password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_current" id="password_current">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="password_new">New password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_new" id="password_new">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_new_again">New password again:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_new_again" id="password_new_again">
        <input type="submit" value="Change">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </div>
</form>


</br>
<form action="changename.php" method="post">    
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->name); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </div>
</form> 


<br />   
<form action="changeemail.php" method="post">      
    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Change email address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->email); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </div>
</form>
<?php
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: How do they conflict? What exactly happens?

Comment: rather than executing the code on the file theyre linked to it goes to them? but if theyre on their own it just execute it like it should, so why having more than 1 per page is an issue idk?

Comment: When you say _it goes to them_, do you mean that the browser loads (for example) `changeemail.php` but does not succeed in executing the form processing code there?  Always when developing code, turn on `display_errors` so errors show on screen -- at the top of your scripts (or in a common include file like `init.php`) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: i had errors turned on and it doesnt give any?, but yes it goes to ''changename.php'' rather than executing the code there for said form ?

Comment: it seems to want to do only the last 1 on the list if that helps? no matter the order

Comment: Make sure that the **rendered** html page doesn't have any HTML syntax errors like miss matching close tags.

Answer (score -1):

Hello You haven't mentioned what problem you actualy facing but this seems like the problem is the unique identification of a form at server side

Please see this post

[Multiple HTML Forms on One Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537918/multiple-html-forms-on-one-page)

Hope this will help ;)

Answer (score -1):

Have each form action set to the current page, and use hidden inputs to determine what action is being taken. Using this method will prevent the user from being dropped onto a different page, and puts the action being taken into a variable that you can use or manipulate.

If you want to have separate PHP scripts for actual functions, use includes or requires.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="changeUsername">
</div>
</form>
```

Then the PHP script gets the action from the POST and uses a switch to determine which functions to call.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    switch ($action) {
        case "changeUsername":
            changeUsername();
            break;
        case "changePassword":
            ...
```

As mentioned, if you want to have these functions in separate php files, you can use include or require.

This conveniently drops the user right back on the same page when they update information, so that they can make additional updates.